# Is there a way to upgrade windows build version without downloading new ISO

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

I'm really eager to download the ubuntu app which requires windows 10 version 16215 or higher.

I currently run windows 10 education version 1703 build 15063.674.

For some reasons, the build preview tab is missing from my windows update settings window, hence preventing me from selecting a newer build to install.

After looking for solutions on this stack exchange I noticed that it was often recommended to just find the newest windows iso and reinstall on top of the current installation to upgrade.

My question is: Is there another way?

Comment: Does this link work for the Education version? https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "Ubuntu app": do you mean Windows Subsystem for Linux? This has been available for some time and I run it on both the 1607 and 1703 releases. It becomes available in **Control Panel** -> **Programs and Features** -> **Windows Features** after you enable **Developer mode** in **Settings** -> **Update & security** -> **For developers**. If you don't have this option, then you need a different Windows licence.

Comment: @Paul magnificent it works

Comment: @AFH I meant the ubuntu app available on the windows store: It should enable the use of an ubuntu command line. Btw, i already had this linux subsystem feature enabled. It's just that the store doesn't allow me to install the ubuntu subsystem because of my (it seems) obsolete OS version. The ubuntu app i'm speaking of can be found here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6

Comment: Looking at the app information, I don't see what it does that is not already in WSL, which does not use the store for installation.

Comment: from my understanding the feature enables the installation of linux subsystems. This app is one of them, namely an ubuntu sub system

Comment: @AFH - Going forward WSL environments will be downloaded through the Windows Store (as of today there are 3).  WSL is out of beta official with the release of 1709.  The Windows Store is the only way to install these WSL environments.  Additionally, developer mode isn't required to install WSL, as of 1709.  Please update yourself on the current feature set of Windows and WSL.  "Looking at the app information, I don't see what it does that is not already in WSL, which does not use the store for installation." - **Yes, as of 1709 it absolutely does.**

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, I was unaware of this change. Since my laptop 1607 system has failed five times to upgrade to 1703 (with a 4GB down-load each time), I am not expecting to get 1709 any time soon.

Comment: @AFH - These changes are well documented.

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm sure they are, but only if you know to look for it. I've not received any news feeds telling me about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update to the latest Windows 10 build, use this link and click "update now":

https://microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10

This will help if you don't have the patience to wait out the staggered release cycle.

Comment: I don't disagree that this answer is correct, but this downloads the ISO, which the author didn't want to do.  Just seems strange the author accepted this answer.

Comment: I am not well acquainted to the microsoft ecosystem and thought that finding a free up-to-date windows iso was a non trivial task for a student owning a "free" (university paid) windows 10 education copy. Moreover I didn't want to bother burning a cd or usb to reinstall the OS (on boot) hence my initial requirement of "not downloading a windows iso".

The fact that this answer proposes  a "one click solution", though relying on a windows iso and hence being less lightweight than i initially desired, is enough for me to be happy with it and accept it :).

Comment: @Ramhound If you are running an upgradable version of Windows, then this page offers an upgrade exe, not an iso. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Ramhound Interesting, my experience was that the page kicked off an upgrade process. I am not sure what the relevance of the download format is?